# Mocking document object with tape js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a module (using tapejs) that is dependent on another module that uses the document object and i get "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

```
// My module i want to test
import { createUrl } from '../config/paths';
// Paths.js
export const url = document.location.toString(); // This is where i'm getting the error.
```

I tried proxyquire to proxy this dependency but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
const store = proxyquire('../../../store/list-store', {
'../config/paths': {
    createUrl: stub(),
},
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Using proxyquire's `noCallThru` method helped me achieve this.

According to proxyquire's docs:

> By default proxyquire calls the function defined on the original dependency whenever it is not found on the stub.
>
> If you prefer a more strict behavior you can prevent callThru on a per
>   module or contextual basis.

My solution:

```
const proxyquireStrict = proxyquire.noCallThru();
const Store = proxyquireStrict('../../../store/booking-add-store', {
    '../config/paths': {
        createUrl: () => stub().returns(''),
    },
}).default;
```